# How to get Powershell to prompt for input parameter

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to PowerShell. There is a command I run many times a day that checks if an AD user account belongs to a couple of AD security groups. Right now, I am pasting the user's account into the command from OneNote and then pasting that command into the PowerShell window. Ideally, I would love to be able to run a .ps1 file that would launch a popup where I could enter in the user's account and the popup would then provide the command output. If that is not possible, run the .ps1 file and have the PowerShell ask for input where I can paste the user's AD account and hit enter. Below is the command I am running. Thank you all in advance.

(Get-ADUser %ADACCOUNT% -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | findstr /i %ADGROUP%

Comment: maybe `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('hello', 'world')` for input and `Out-GridView` for output.

Comment: Thank you Santiago. I am sorry if I sound helpless but could you please explain how I would put your suggestion to use with regards to the command I provided?

Comment: maybe by looking into my answer

Comment: Thank you so much Santiago! That works great! Is it possible to have the entire command contained in the .ps1 file? If so, where would I put the "somegroup1"? I tried modifying some of the variables like $group but that just broke the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea to get you started using [`InputBox` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) to get the input user, [`MessageBox.Show` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) in case the user was not part of any group and [`Out-GridView`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.2) in case the user was member of at least one of the groups.

Usage is quite simple, you just name this script as whatever you want and then when calling it, you can do `.\myScript.ps1 -ADGroups 'somegroup1', 'somegroup2', etc`

```bash
param([string[]] $ADGroups)

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic, System.Windows.Forms

# Get user input
$choice = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox(
    'Input User SamAccountName',
    'Choose a Title for me')

# if the user didn't provide any input, exit script
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($choice)) {
    return
}
# get user membership and filter
$result = (Get-ADUser $choice -Properties memberOf).memberOf | Where-Object {
    # where the DistinguishedName matches any of input AD Groups
    foreach ($group in $ADGroups) {
        if ($_ -match ([regex]::Escape($group)) {
            return $true
        }
    }
}

# if no results found
if (-not $result) {
    # show this message and exit the script
    [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
        "$choice was not a member of any AD Group",
        'Choose a Title for me',
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)

    return
}

# otherwise, show this grid that contains the list of DistinguishedNames
# the user is a member of
$result | Out-GridView
```